# HTML DIV inline

Tags: css, html

So, I have 2 DIV elements in the same line. But when I put content on the second one, the first one goes down. Here's the code and it's result.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uWkJZ/)

```
<div style="margin-top: 5px;"></div>
<div style="display: inline-block; width:250px; height:180px; background-color:#fff; box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);">
    <center>
        <div style="font-weight: bold; text-align: center; width: 250px; height: 50px; font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif; color:#000; font-size:12px; border:0; height:100%; line-height: 30px;">Top 5 Números Ganhadores 1º -</div>
    </center>
</div>
<div style="display: inline-block; width:250px; height:180px; background-color:#fff; box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);">
    <center>
        <div style="font-weight: bold; text-align: center; width: 250px; height: 50px; font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif; color:#000; font-size:12px; border:0; height:100%; line-height: 30px;">Top 5 Números Escolhidos
            <p>1º -</div>
    </center>
</div>
```

Comment: Are your div's always going to be 250px by 180px ?

Comment: Only those 2 that I've shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you have an error in your syntax

```
<div style="margin-top: 5px;"> </div>
<div style="display: inline-block; width:250px; height:180px; background-color:#fff; box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);">
<center>
    <div style="font-weight: bold; text-align: center; width: 250px; height: 50px; font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif; color:#000; font-size:12px; border:0; height:100%; line-height: 30px;">
        Top 5 Números Ganhadores
        1º -
    </div>
</center>
</div>
<div style="display: inline-block; width:250px; height:180px; background-color:#fff; box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);">
<center>
    <div style="font-weight: bold; text-align: center; width: 250px; height: 50px; font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif; color:#000; font-size:12px; border:0; height:100%; line-height: 30px;">
        Top 5 Números Escolhidos<p>
        1º - 
    </div>
</center>
</div>
```

You have an opening P tag that you never closed after "Top 5 Números Escolhidos"

```
Top 5 Números Escolhidos<p>
        1º -
```

Remove that and you'll be good to go!

http://jsfiddle.net/S636H/

**Edit:**

Want to put more than just text in the divs? Just float both of the divs to the left, and make sure you close the p tag.

```
<div style="margin-top: 5px;"> </div>
<div style="display: inline-block; width:250px; height:180px; background-color:#fff; box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);">
<center>
    <div style="font-weight: bold; text-align: center; width: 250px; height: 50px; font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif; color:#000; font-size:12px; border:0; height:100%; line-height: 30px; float:left;">
        Top 5 Números Ganhadores
        1º -
    </div>
</center>
</div>
<div style="display: inline-block; width:250px; height:180px; background-color:#fff; box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);">
<center>
    <div style="font-weight: bold; text-align: center; width: 250px; height: 50px; font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif; color:#000; font-size:12px; border:0; height:100%; line-height: 30px; float:left;">
        Top 5 Números Escolhidos<p></p>
        1º - 
    </div>
</center>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/48wAA/

OR, if you don't want to float the divs make sure that the p tag is inline:
http://jsfiddle.net/CkGJf/

Comment: Can't remove the <p> because I want a paragraph. Unless there's another way to get a paragraph there

Comment: Having the <p> is fine, but you need to end it... In your code, it never ends, and so your code fails to work as it is not coded properly. You need <p> and </p>, put your paragraph content inside the <p></p> tags.

Comment: @Michael - not so. Try it by modifying FábioMartinho's original JSfiddle, you'll see it makes no difference. Chris B is actually changing the issue by floating the boxes.

Answer (score 0):

The essence of what you are trying to do is as follows:

```
<div class="parentPanel">
    <div class="boxyPanel">The Left Div</div>
    <div class="boxyPanel">The Right Div</div>
</div>
```

And the CSS to do the styling is:

```
.parentPanel {
background-color: #f0f0f0;
overflow: auto;
text-align: center;    
}
.boxyPanel {
display: inline-block;
width: 250px;
height: 150px;
border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

See the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/GVgun/